# Memory leak in google maps in android

Tags: android, google-maps, memory-leaks, crash

How to release holded object from google map in Android. I have tried removing fragment, System.gc etc still app is consuming lot of memory, and finally it crashes. Also I have increased heap size. Please help me.

Comment: Use MAT to analyse memory leaks.It should help

Comment: This [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html) might help you monitor your activities which causes leaks. You may also look at this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3803#c32) which suggest that you have to reuse the maps and not destroy it. The best that you can do for now is to handle memory leaks on Android in general.